# Execute Procedure in Oracle

Tags: variables, oracle10g, procedure

I have a procedure name which is stored in a variable.
Now,how do I execute that procedure in Oracle 10g
Any links or answers would be of much help!!
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare text statement and call it with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE